# Array Adapter returns NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout

I am just trying to fill my ListView but I get a NullPointerException

Here is the code

```
    String[] values = new String[] { "Reset Company", "Reset Demographic"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    settingsOptions.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The LogCat says there is a NullPointException on this line `settingsOptions.setAdapter(adapter);`

How can i resolve this?

Comment: I think settingsOptions is null there .Please provice full code of oncreate.......

Comment: what is settingsOptions? That could be null!

Comment: It would help if you'd post the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve it by giving `settingsOptions` a valid value instead of `null`.

Chances are you are doing a `findViewById` with an invalid *id*, or before the view is actually put there by `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

as per T`he LogCat says there is a NullPointException on this line settingsOptions.setAdapter(adapter);`

it looks settingsOptions is null there .